# How to navigate between pages on React Native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, navigation

I understand that this is a common question, but I cannot seem to get this to work.

I want to just be able to navigate to another screen on the click of a button. I have seen many people using these Stacks and installing many dependencies. Firstly, when I install these dependencies I run into many errors, and secondly, my App.js file currently returns one of my existing screens. And I cannot seem to find an example where they return a screen in the App.js function when they use these Stacks.

If someone could show me the best way to implement this feature or link the best example, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the starting guide of React Navigator [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to navigate between in only 2 screens you can use conditional rendering in your App.js like this :
...
return (
someCondition ? Component1 : Component2;
)

but I personally suggest you to use react navigation since it's the right way to naviagte between screens

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're going to use [react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/).Your App.js function could be the following:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

function App({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home</Text>
      <Button
        title="Another Screen"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Another')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

The function above will navigate to a different screen with the onClick on the button.

Comment: So, with 'Another', how do you define another in App.js? Because I have seen examples where people have something like "import Screen1 from 'root...'".

Comment: I imported the screen that I am trying to navigate to via a button press and replaced "Another" with my screen name, and I get the error: "navigation.navigate is not a function. (In 'navigation.navigate("SignUpScreen")', 'navigation.navigate' is undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy example:

```
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        title="Go to Profile"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function ProfileScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        title="Go to Notifications"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
      />
      <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
    </View>
  );
}

function NotificationsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        title="Go to Settings"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Settings')}
      />
      <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyStack />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

[Example in Expo](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=Authentication%20flows%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40%5E0.1.7%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%40%5E5.8.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%40%5E5.9.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%40%5E5.2.16%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%40%5E5.2.16%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%40%5E5.7.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%40%5E5.9.0%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E4.0.1%2Creact-native-reanimated%40%5E1.7.0%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40%5E3.0.2%2Creact-native-screens%40%5E2.9.0%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E2.15.1&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Fsimple-stack.js)

Comment: My issue here is that you have defined all the pages on the App.js file, my screens will be quite detailed and thus I cannot be writing the code for all screens in one single file.

Comment: You can import an external component (screen) and use it .

   ```import {ScreenX} from './path_to_screenX'
.......
   <Stack.Screen name="ScreenX" component={ScreenX} />```